# I want to select the same value from multiple rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

**data_table info**

```
idx | type | value
 1  |   1  |  1
 2  |   2  |  2
 3  |   3  |  3
 4  |   4  |  4
```

**query**

```
SELECT * FROM data_table WHERE idx IN (1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 4, 4, 1);
```

I receive this current result:

```
idx | type | value
 1  |   1  |  1
 2  |   2  |  2
 3  |   3  |  3
 4  |   4  |  4
```

But I intend to receive the following result:

```
idx | type | value
 1  |   1  |  1
 1  |   1  |  1
 2  |   2  |  2
 1  |   1  |  1
 1  |   1  |  1
 3  |   3  |  3
 4  |   4  |  4
 4  |   4  |  4
 1  |   1  |  1
```

How can I change my query to receive my desired result?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid of you should use `union all` to write some ugly sql:

```
select * from data_table where idx = 1
union all 
select * from data_table where idx = 1
union all
select * from data_table where idx = 2
union all 
select * from data_table where idx = 1
union all
select * from data_table where idx = 1
union all
select * from data_table where idx = 3
union all
select * from data_table where idx = 4
union all
select * from data_table where idx = 4
union all
select * from data_table where idx = 1
```

Or something like this:

```
select data_table.*
from (
    select 1 idx
    union all select 1
    union all select 1
    union all select 2
    union all select 1
    union all select 1
    union all select 3
    union all select 4
    union all select 4
    union all select 1
) t
left join data_table
on t.idx = data_table.idx
```

***Note:*** The second way will get you different order and it's inspired by [**@Willem Van Onsem**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67579/willem-van-onsem)

Answer (score 0):

A potential way to solve this is **creating a table on the fly** and then perform a `JOIN`:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ids (id INT NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO ids VALUES (1), (1), (2), (1), (1), (3), (4), (4), (1);

SELECT data_table.* FROM
FROM ids JOIN data_table ON data_table.idx = ids.id;

DROP ids;
```

Comment: thank you. i think, used temporary table more  then union all.

Answer (score 0):

If you need get rows that order, what you will hard coded, then you can simulate  additional column (`ord` in this case) and then use this column in `ORDER BY` clause:

```
 SELECT data_table.* FROM data_table
 inner join (
      select 1 as idx, 1 as ord
      union all
      select 1 as idx, 2 as ord
      union all
      select 2 as idx, 3 as ord
      union all
      select 1 as idx, 4 as ord
      union all
      select 1 as idx, 5 as ord
      union all
      select 3 as idx, 6 as ord
      union all
      select 4 as idx, 7 as ord
      union all
      select 4 as idx, 8 as ord
      union all
      select 1 as idx, 9 as ord
) your_list
on
data_table.idx = your_list.idx
order by your_list.ord
```